# Issue regarding view in android app

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app and while moving from one activity to other I am getting the data but view is not as expected.
 I am posting my view image.

[image]

Comment: please post you layout's xml.

Comment: Please provide more details. If you are using Relative layout & set text to textview then you have to set some properties to textview like android:layout_below="@+id/tvTextView1" to Textview2.

Comment: Without the code, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: You should provide more details while asking any question, also provide your code where you're facing issue.